# Passing Row of 2-Dimensional Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

My objective is to write a simple code that intends to find the sum of all the rows of a matrix. For doing this task I've made a function `sum(int c int x[])`. In this function, the first argument is the number of columns, and the second argument is a one-dimensional array. The second parameter is supposed to receive a particular row of the matrix at a time so that I can calculate the sum of the elements of it.

For the first row the output is all right, but from the second row onward the output is garbage.

For example, if I give this input matrix ...

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

... then the desired output is:

```
6
15
24
```

but, actually I'm getting something like this:

```
6
2004638605
1346689939
```

Here's my code:

```
int sum(int c, int x[c])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(--c; c >= 0; c--)    
        sum = sum + x[c];

    return sum;
}

void getMatrix(int r, int c, int x[][c])
{
     int i, j;

     for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
     {
          for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
          {
               printf("Enter a No. = ");
               scanf("%d", &x[i][j]);
          }
     }
}

void display (int r, int c, int x[][c])
{
     int i, j;

     for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
     {
          for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
          {
               printf("%d \t", x[i][j]);
          }
          printf("\n");
     }
}
int main()
{
    int a[7][7], r, c, i;

    printf("Enter the Dimensions of the Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);

    getMatrix(r, c, a);

    printf("SHOWING MATRIX : \n");
    display(r, c, a);

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
        printf("%d \n", sum(c, a[i]));
}
```

I'm trying to compile and run this code using the TDM GCC compiler.

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be in the code posted. As a side note not related to the bug you describe, the sum function should be rewritten as `for(int i=0; i<c; i++) { sum += x[i]; }`.

Comment: Can you show how you are reading the matrix(`getMatrix`)?

Comment: Please rea this: [mcve]

Comment: the posted code is missing the prototypes for functions: ` `getMatrix()` and `display()` and is missing the `#include`` statements for any needed header files

Comment: OT:  variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like: a[][], r, c, are meaningless even the current context

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Those functions return the number of successful input conversion specifications.  (in this case any returned value other than 2 indicates an error occurred

Comment: regarding: `for(i = 0; i < c; i++)`   This should be counting the number of rows, not the number of columns

Comment: OT: regarding: `int sum(int c, int x[c])
{
    int sum = 0;`   and `return sum;`   it is a very poor programming practice to name a local variable the same as the function containing that variable

Comment: regarding: `int a[7][7]`  how do you know the values entered by the user for number rows and number of columns will both be 7?    Suggest using the VLA (Variable Length Array) feature of C and not declare that array until after the statement: `scanf("%d%d", &r, &c);`

Comment: OT:  never trust the user to do the right thing.  Strongly suggest checking the values 'r' and 'c' to assure they are both above 0 (and not too large)

Comment: @Lundin The user has added the missing functions to the question, so I think it should no longer be on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the code visible in the question.

As you didn't show the functions `getMatrix` and `display`, I created a minimal example that uses the matrix shown in your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int c, int x[c])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(--c; c >= 0; c--)    
        sum = sum + x[c];

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int a[7][7] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int r = 3, c = 3, i;

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++) /* since your example has 3 rows and 3 columns you would not notice the wrong loop limit here (c instead of r) */
        printf("%d \n", sum(c, a[i]));
}
```

This prints

```
6 
15 
24
```

as expected.

I guess function `getMatrix` doesn't put the data to the correct array elements.
Probably it uses the number of rows and columns specified as function arguments instead of the real array size `int a[7][7]`.

Edit: After the missing functions have been added to the question, it is clear that `getMatrix` and `display` do not correctly access the array.

When you declare the function as

```
void getMatrix(int r, int c, int x[][c])
```

and call the function with e.g `c=3` the function thinks that you are passing an array with 3 columns while in main you declared `a[7][7]` to have 7 columns. The calculation of the memory location for a two-dimensional array needs the correct number of columns.

A quick fix for your original program would be to declare the functions as

```
void getMatrix(int r, int c, int x[][7])
```

and

```
void display (int r, int c, int x[][7])
```

Instead of using a magic number 7 I suggest to use a `#define` both for declaring the array `a` and for the function arguments.

BTW: Compare your program with the code in this answer. I fixed the loop around `printf(... sum...)` which counts the rows, not the columns.

A better solution would be to dynamically allocate the memory for array `a` based on the number of rows and columns and calculate the index yourself, e.g.

```
index = selected_row * number_of_columns + selected_column;
```

Comment: Hello, Mr. Bodo. I've edited the post and also shared the code of display () and getMatrix () functions. Please go through it. And reply if you find any discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is solved, after following your suggestion.